# Why my render gets overexposed and blurred after the actual calculation?

Tags: rendering, objects, lighting, denoise, blur

While rendering everything is fine, but when 100% rendered the objects become blurry and there is some kind of intense light added to the image:

[image]

While rendering everything is fine (image while rendering):

[image]

**Q:** Why my render gets overexposed and blurred after the actual calculation?

Comment: This looks like an effect done in the compositor, make sure you don't have any effect nodes in the compositor editor

Comment: Hi Jameela. Please take your time when asking a question, makes it way easier for us to understand your question and to provide a solution as well... Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you and sorry, I dont know good english

Comment: @Gorgious I got rid of the filters (glare and bokeh blur) thank you for pointing that out. I just downloaded this file and im pretty new to this. Once ive done that the lighting didnt work at all, whether I use the mesh or the sun

Comment: Make sure there is still a link between the render layer and the output node

Comment: Hi Jameela, maybe you should provide your blend file so we can check it out and help you?